# Excel - VLOOKUP via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to know how exactly to incorporate a `VLOOKUP` function into my Excel worksheet via `VBA`; I am completely comfortable with the `VLOOKUP` function when entering it directly into a cell, but I am completely new to VBA.

A little info:

- I have ~5500 rows of data;
- I have a number of named ranges (such as `catNo`, `catNoRange`, to name but two);
- I want to use VBA to check `catNo` against `catNoRange` and return the value of the sixth (6th) column in `catNoRange`;

I also want to know how - and where - to display the result once I have it; ideally I would like it to appear in cell J4 (and the corresponding cells down to J5500).

How can I achieve this?

**Additional Info:**

For those of you wondering why I don't just use a regular `VLOOKUP` to achieve this: I want to use VBA because I have written a script which checks to see if certain cells are empty, and if at least one of them is populated, then the `VLOOKUP` will execute, taking the value of the populated cell for the main search critera.

**Code Update:**

Following some advice, I have opted to attempt to use the `Find` function instead of `VLOOKUP`.  It doesn't work; here is what I have:

```
Sub findCode()

    Result = WorksheetFunction.Find("ABI0010P", "5012616173004", "33787")
    Range("J4").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you not use `Find`? Much quicker and more VBA friendly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I doubt it (see "Additional Info:" section that I have added in).  Unless, of course, you can explain how.

Comment: _If you wish to perform a Lookup in VBA it seems that many opt to use the Vlookup WorksheetFunction in their code. While this can be done, it is a slow means of looking up data. This is because when we are in VBA we can use the extremely fast Find Method._ (from OzGrid page on various types of Lookup functions in excel: http://www.ozgrid.com/News/LookUpMatchIndexVBAFind.htm)

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible to display the result within cell `J4` (and down towards J5500) like I want to, instead of displaying it in a message box?

Comment: Yes you should be able to run that quite easily. Just write the result to `Range("J4").Value` or else if you need to do for J4:J5500 (or if you are unsure of the number of rows, "Find" is one of many ways you can find the total number of rows) then you can do so as well by running it in a loop `For i=4 to 5500 'or your last row`....`Next i`

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't working for me; I typed it as per your instruction, but am receiving "Invalide use of Property" error.  Any suggestions?  My full code for finding and displaying the data is:
    `Result = WorksheetFunction.Find("ABI0010P", "5012616173004", "33787")`
    `Range("J4").Value`

Comment: `Find` is not a `WorksheetFunction` and cant make out what variables you have passed to it there but they dont look as they should. Can you please add all code to the OP to make it easier to see what you are working with?

Comment: The recommendation was NOT for the Worksheetfunction Find; but rather for the VBA Range.Find method.  Look up Range.Find in VBA help

Answer (score 0):

For the find function you want to have something like this

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(2)
Rowz = ws.Cells(rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
k = 2
searchvalue= ws.Cells(k, 2)
Set SEARCHRANGE= ws.Range("A2:A" & Rowz)
Set Findx = SEARCHRANGE.find(searchvalue, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not Findx Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(k, 4) = "what ever you want"
```